# Place progressbar fixed top of screen without nesting

Tags: android

I have a layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/space_medium"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space_medium">
```

I want to place a progress bar at the top of the screen fixed so even if the user scrolls they can see it.

I prefer not to wrap the NestedScrollView in another constraint layout.

And even better I would like to reuse this in all other activities or fragments that need it.

is there an easy way that works with AndroidStudios preview feature?

Answer (score 1):

Insert this code into the layout file.

```
<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a custom toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I then set the toolbar in my activity onCreate:

```
setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbarContainer.toolbar)
```

activity layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data></data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar_container"
            tools:visibility="visible" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

I can then access the progressbar everywhere with

```
binding.toolbarContainer.progressBar.visibility =
      if (state is Loading) View.VISIBLE else View.INVISIBLE
```